# How do I override an object that is being passed into a method to string?

Tags: java, overriding

It's exactly as the title says, I am trying to pass an object into a method, so that I can compare strings. The object doesn't convert properly, showing up as "MediaItem@9a2", and I know I have to use override but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

```
public class MediaItem {                                                
private String title;                                               
                                            
public String getTitle() {                                              
    return title;                                               
}                                               
                                            
public void setTitle(String title) {                                                
    this.title = title;                                             
}                                               
public MediaItem(String t)                                              
{                                               
    setTitle(t);                                                
}                                               
                                            
public MediaItem()                                              
{                                               
                                            
}                                               
                                            
public boolean equals(Object obj)                                               
{                                               
String temptitle = getTitle();                                              
temptitle = temptitle.toLowerCase();                                                
temptitle = temptitle.trim();                                               
//    System.out.println(temptitle);                                                
                                            
                                            
String tempobj = obj.toString();                                                
System.out.println(tempobj);                                                
tempobj=tempobj.toLowerCase();                                              
tempobj= tempobj.trim();                                                
System.out.println(tempobj);                                                
                                            
                                            
if (temptitle.equals(tempobj))                                              
{                                               
System.out.println("this");                                             
return true;                                                
}                                               
else{                                               
return false;                                               
}                                               
                                            
}                                               
                                            
@Override                                               
public String toString()                                                
{                                               
return obj.title;                                               
}                                               
                                            
}
```

There's a bad attempt at overriding at the bottom of the code. Also, not sure why all the colour has disappeared from the code.

Edit: Ok maybe I should add some more explanation: The task is to compare the obj sent in and the title of the current object. If they match, I return true. If not, I return false. The only thing I am allowed to change is the stuff within the equals(object obj) method. I can also add override. That's it. Is there an easier way to do this than what I was trying to do?

Comment: What is `obj` inside your `toString` method? You just need to return `title` because you're interested in the title of the current instance. Also for comparing objects you should override `equals` and `hashCode` rather than comparing the outputs of the `toString` method.

Comment: You're equals implementation is not how you would usually do it. You usually don't just do `obj.toString()`and then work with that. insetad you would usually check if the passed object is of the same class as the owning this object and if that is the case you would cast `obj` to `MediaItem` and then work with the casted object that allows you to actually access the methods and fields of that class.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You cannot externally override the toString, you *can* write custom string serialization outside the object and access the members using the getter. But that sounds wrong. Override the toString in the class directly. And generally comparing objects based on their string representation is a bad idea. Instead implement proper equals or compareTo.

Comment: Replying to @QBrute, Ye thanks that worked. Just had to put "return title" in the override is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String toString()                                                
{                                               
     return title;                                               
}
```

is sufficient you could also use `return this.title;` however the `this` is implicit as there are no other title defined in the method

Answer (score 1):

To get human readable representation of the object you should override `toString()` method, that's correct. However you should do it like that:

```
public String toString() {
   return title; // No obj!
}
// or like that
public String toString() {
 return "MyClass{title=" + title + "}";
}
```

What you are doing wrong is comparing objects. It's a complex topic but there is a quick example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o != null
        && getClass() == o.getClass()
        && Objects.equals(title.toLowerCase().trim(),
            o.title.toLowerCase().trim()); // for each field
}
```

Comment: consider adding the same parameters as in the question by changing the last line to `&& Objects.equals(title.toLowerCase().trim(), o.title.toLowerCase().trim()); // for each field`

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `toString()` method is when you wanna do some custom external serialization for the `toString()` rather than the usual object hashed code. For comparing obj using `equal()`, you need to custom the equals method depends on your needs, like fields comparision, hashed comparison, etc.